# How to extract nested list data from a GeoJSON file in each key into dataframe

Tags: python, json, parsing, geojson

I have a GeoJSON file with multiple keys. I want to extract the `name` and `coordinates`. I can access each of the elements, but I do not know how to loop over them to add them into a dataframe or another appropriate format maybe like dict. I want the name with the corresponding coordinates (lat,lon). The final use of the dataframe or dict will be to plot it with Plotly.

The GeoJSON looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "sf_example",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "FirstRoad"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiLineString",
                "coordinates": [[[-0.209607278927995, 51.516851589085569], [-0.209607278927995, 51.516851589085569], [-0.210671042775843, 51.51666770991379], [-0.217526409795308, 51.515064252076257]]]
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "SecondRoad"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiLineString",
                "coordinates": [[[-0.208969020619286, 51.516005738748845], [-0.208969020619286, 51.516005738748845], [-0.211096548314982, 51.512688382789257]]]
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "ThirdRoad"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiLineString",
                "coordinates": [[[-0.204725784826204, 51.517020757267986], [-0.204725784826204, 51.517020757267986], [-0.207798880386654, 51.517211990108905]]]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I read the data with the following code:

```
import json
with open('sf_example.geojson', "r") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
```

And with that code I can access the elements:

```
data['features'][0]['properties']['name']
data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
```

How do I loop so that all information will be extracted? What I want as a result is a dataframe or dict like this for example:

```
name,lat,lon
FirstRoad,-0.209607278927995, 51.516851589085569, 
FirstRoad,-0.209607278927995, 51.516851589085569, 
FirstRoad,-0.210671042775843, 51.51666770991379, 
FirstRoad,-0.217526409795308, 51.515064252076257,
SecondRoad,-0.208969020619286, 51.516005738748845,
SecondRoad,-0.208969020619286, 51.516005738748845, 
SecondRoad,-0.211096548314982, 51.512688382789257
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to iterate over the features in the GeoJSON file and extract the name and coordinates for each feature. The extracted information is then stored in a [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

# fill data

rows = []
for feature in data['features']:
    name = feature['properties']['name']
    coordinates = feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
    for lat, lon in coordinates:
        rows.append((name, lat, lon))

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['name', 'lat', 'lon'])

print(df)
```

This results in:

```
         name       lat        lon
0   FirstRoad -0.209607  51.516852
1   FirstRoad -0.209607  51.516852
2   FirstRoad -0.210671  51.516668
3   FirstRoad -0.217526  51.515064
4  SecondRoad -0.208969  51.516006
5  SecondRoad -0.208969  51.516006
6  SecondRoad -0.211097  51.512688
7   ThirdRoad -0.204726  51.517021
8   ThirdRoad -0.204726  51.517021
9   ThirdRoad -0.207799  51.517212
```